# First time Linux installer. Keyboard does not work at all

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

[image]

I installed Ubuntu onto a flash drive. Booted it. My keyboard doesn't work so I'm stuck using the on-screen keyboard. I can't connect to the internet because I'm on campus wifi and I have to install a separate certificate to be able to connect to the internet but for some reason Ubuntu won't bring up the next page/popup when I try to access the Linux certificate package from the wireless setup network. Ubuntu boots by default and I don't get this boot menu everyone talks about online. I'm just using my phone as a hotspot until I can do what I can to fix this. My laptop is basically a big paper weight at the moment.  I've done surfing and a not too many people have had their whole keyboard not work. I've tried the

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

and reboot method. Didn't work. I just want to go back to windows at this point because I don't think I'm ready for this. How do I access the boot/grub boot up menu without being able to use my shift or escape key?

[image]

Comment: You have a laptop, yes? There's one of two possibilities... you have an old BIOS, or you've installed a Ubuntu version with a possible bad kernel. The only way to move forward is to connect a hardwired USB keyboard. Then you can troubleshoot the first two possibilities.

Comment: Did you try using an external USB keyboard, probably one from your computer lab?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `ls -al /boot`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I forgot... I need to know the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema I added the screenshot of the terninal to the post. Also, it is a Surface Laptop 2, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 256GB SSD

Comment: Sorry, but Microsoft is having a problem with my account... but, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57515 for BIOS update info. Report back.

Comment: Also, you're behind on Ubuntu Software Updates, so start `Software Updater`, and update, and then reboot and retest the keyboard.

Comment: @heynnema I am updating the software now. This isn't related to the post directly but even though my USB is not plugged in, I can still run Ubuntu. When I boot with UEFI and disable Ubuntu in the boot manager, it still runs. I can't go back to Windows OS no matter what I do

Comment: Confusion here... I just reread your question, and you said that you installed Ubuntu to a flash drive (not a good idea). But now you say *"even though my USB is not plugged in"*, do you mean USB keyboard, or USB flash drive?

Comment: @heynnema my USB flash drive is not plugged in

Comment: If your USB flash drive is not plugged in, and you're able to still run Ubuntu, then you probably installed Ubuntu on your internal SSD/HDD... and depending on other choice that you made at installation time... Windows **may** be gone. In Boot Manager, does it show Windows AND Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema yes. There is windows, ubuntu, and other drive options. If I leave windows the only one checked, it boots directly into UEFI so it seems I can only boot Ubuntu. Maybe windows is gone

Comment: Finish your Ubuntu updates, reboot, and see if the keyboard starts to work. Then start `gparted` and get a screenshot, and edit that into your question... and let's see if there's a ntfs partition on your SSD/HDD.

Comment: @heynnema keyboard isn't working on laptop. Added in Gparted picture

Comment: Windows is gone. Try the BIOS update that I referred to earlier. If your current BIOS doesn't support self-updating, then you'd need Windows to install it... so you'll need to research how to update BIOS on a Surface 2, to know.