# Installed Ubuntu and lost Windows in the process. What do I do?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu. Had a problem where my laptop keyboard wouldn't work with Ubuntu, only external keyboards. I wasn't sure if I wanted to keep Ubuntu because of that but now I can't even load Windows. When I boot UEFI, windows boot manager is an option but when it's the only one selected, it just boots back into UEFI automatically. If I check, internal storage, Ubuntu boots even though I thought I installed it on a USB. At this point, I'm fine with losing any data I had because everything I need is in the cloud. I just want Windows back and Ubuntu gone. I have a Surface Laptop 2 I5, 256GB SSD.

[GParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APCFD.jpg)

Comment: We don't have Windows for you, but it is easy to download and reinstall. How to do it goes beyond this site's on topics, but I am sure you can easily find instructions.

Comment: Looks like you gave Ubuntu your whole disk, or am I missing something?

Comment: See previous question for background.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277973/first-time-linux-installer-keyboard-does-not-work-at-all

Comment: Will need woeusb or mkusb to make a Windows USB that boots, if doing from Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)